# Efeito em formulário (CSS)

Tags: javascript, css

Alguém sabe se esse tipo de estilo dos inputs do site abaixo tem um nome, já vi esse efeito de transição de label em diversos forms mas não achei o nome dessa técnica.

Site: https://app.nutrebem.com.br/signup

Comment: [Material Design](https://material.io/guidelines/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-layout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse efeito é geralmente de frameworks modularizadas, e também um padrão especificado no famoso artigo [Material Design](https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/introduction.html)

em angular você pode pode obte-los na sessão de inputs do [angular material inputs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input)

em react a mesma coisa [react material inputs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/auto-complete)

até mesmo em [Bootstrap material](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/#input)

Comment: Muito obrigado, não tinha conhecimento do material do Angular.

Comment: Denada haha!, não esqueça de selecionar a resposta que te ajudou como melhor, fica no canto superior esquerdo, abaixo dos votos, isso ajuda o site e outros usuários